# Can not connect MongoDB docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Can not connect mongodb run in docker-compose

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/500ae_cms`

[image]

[image]

error:

`MongoDB connection error: mongodb://db:27017/500ae_cms`.

`MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [db:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [Array],
}]`

docker-compose file
[image]

Comment: Will the docker community please sort out your tag information and general question policy. Networking and configuration questions such as this really should not be present on Stack Overflow, which is a site for **Programming** questions. This is not one of those, and clearly about networking. A such it would be appreciated that the appropriate site should instead be https://serverfault.com

Comment: better to post docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @Adiii I updated docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

For your db service you expose port 27775 but in your app you try to connect to 27017.

Docker resolves the service name in an IP address but this fails here (too?)

```
failed to connect to server [db:27017];;; getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
```

should at least be something like:

```
failed to connect to server [db:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 17.19.0.2:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running `nslookup db` from the api container? If that resolves, then it might be an issue with your mongo driver.